# Large Data set load - Server Side or Client Side

Tags: sql, performance, load

I'm looking for anybody out there that has implemented large SQL sp's data returns to AG-Grid without waiting many minutes for load to screen?

I'm struggling getting this implemented without having to wait and wait.

When I say large data, I'm talking 50,000+ records.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: We're hooking through API's to SQL

Answer (score 0):

We're hooking through API's to SQL